# Using CTE to delete true duplicates in Greenplum

Tags: sql, duplicates, greenplum

I am trying to delete true duplicates using CTE but I'm getting the below error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETE"
LINE 60: DELETE FROM CTE where row_num=2;
         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "DELETE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1125
```

My code -

```
WITH CTE AS (select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY column1,
column2,
column3
ORDER BY column2 DESC, column3 asc ) AS row_num,
column1,
column2,
column3
column4
load_feed_num
from MT_TABLE_NAME
where column2='some value here')
DELETE FROM CTE where row_num=2;
```

If I replace `DELETE FROM CTE where row_num=2;` with `SELECT * FROM CTE where row_num=2;`.

I get the result immediately. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Dbms name please

Comment: It's in the tag. Greenplum is my dbms

Comment: Why did you double post this question?

Comment: @JonRoberts two different approaches to same problem. Hence two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Select query not a Table that you are deleting from.
What you can do is you can have table name like below and further some common column with the same table matching with CTE

`Delete from table where.... CTE...etc code`

Answer (score 0):

Use Row_Number to get the records you want to preserve (=1)
And delete from the underlying table everything else.
Or use the CTE to JOIN on underlying table by using the primary key.